# Cannot add PPA. Fresh ubuntu installation (20.04) I have tried quite a few things

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, ppa

I am trying to add deadsnakes ppa to install some python versions. I have tried to use the `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` command, but I get *Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~deadsnakes/ubuntu/ppa'. ERROR: '~deadsnakes' user or team does not exist.*.

I have seen many posts on this, but none of the solutions provided help. I have tried:

1. Reinstalling ca-certificates with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates`.
2. Reinstalling ca-certificates with

   ```
      sudo apt remove --purge ca-certificates
      sudo apt autoremove
      sudo apt install ca-certificates
      sudo apt install software-properties-common
   ```
3. Using `sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`
4. I have checked if the firewall was interfering (it wasn't activated).
5. Checked the clock.

None of this has solved it.

I just installed Ubuntu coming from Windows, so I don't have much of an idea of how this works. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this help https://ubuntu.social/@launchpadstatus/110594525393361192

Comment: I have tried it. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the repository without `add-apt-repository`:

Import [the gpg key](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?fingerprint=on&op=index&search=0xF23C5A6CF475977595C89F51BA6932366A755776):

```
gpg --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys F23C5A6CF475977595C89F51BA6932366A755776
```

Move the key to `/usr/share/keyrings/` (dearmored):

```
gpg --export  F23C5A6CF475977595C89F51BA6932366A755776 |
sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/deadsnakes.pgp
```

Set up the repository:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/deadsnakes.pgp] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal main" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/deadsnakes.list
```

Install the desired package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install package_name
```

Edit:

To install `gnupg2` you need to enable `universe` repository. [See here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

Comment: first command returned ```gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure```.

Comment: @MvCast `sudo apt reinstall gnupg2`.

Comment: ```Package 'gnupg2' has no installation candidate```

Comment: @MvCast see my edit please.